# How do I limit Google Maps API's Search Box results to a country?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, search-box

I don't want to use autocomplete, I want to limit search to a country using the Search Box (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#SearchBoxOptions), the only option is bounds.  You could limit the result to the bounds of your country of interest.

Comment: Many countries don't cleanly fit in a bounding box, also that option provides a "bias" and explicitly says it's not a restriction.